# How to limit current on parallel outputs from a power supply?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, usb, usb-device, current-limiting

So I am trying to make a USB power dock for multiple devices. I have a 5v 20A power supply.

If I connect 10 USB ports in parallel, is there a way to cap their current to 5v 2A?
I don't want to fry my USB powered devices by plugging it to a port connected in parallel with a 5v 20A power supply... I mean, won't that damage my devices? I am not even sure here.

Answer (score 1):

It is not needed. A device will 'drain' energy from its power source, the power source will not use 'all' of its Amps to connected devices.

That means , with a 5V 20A power source, you can add as many devices from 5V upto a total of 20A (or a bit less to keep some margin).

You will get in problems, if you connect devices totaling more than 2A to a 5V 2A power source.

So you can better keep the 20A power source.

Comment: Sorry if I am being a noob again, but usually when I connect a 1A rated phone on the 2A rated power port on my powerbank, it usually heats up alot. I was assuming something similar would happen and then it's a 100W power supply directly connected to that USB. Just being cautious before setting it up.

Comment: It should not matter if you are connecting your 1A rated phone on a 2A or 20A power bank. Note however, that charging batteries can cause some heat. If you connect a 4A telephone (if they exist) to a 2A power bank, the power bank will probably get broken (possibly after some time), because the power source cannot deliver the required current.

Comment: @SamiulHoque When you connect 1A phone to 2A powerbank it heats up not because powerbank "feeds" it full 2A, but because your phone happily _draws_ 1A, as opposed to only 500mA available from regular USB port. As Michel said above, some heating is pretty normal for high current charging.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation @Maple. I guess I'll plug it all up and wait for the smoke test :D

Comment: @MichelKeijzers unless we are talking about extremely cheap and badly designed powerbanks, they all have over-current and short-circuit protection. They won't be damaged by device attempting to draw more.

Comment: @Maple True indeed, in this case it's not applicable (assuming the USB has protection, it's more for DIY projects.